# Dynamics CRM 2016 Claims-Based 404 Errors

Tags: asp.net, iis, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, adfs

We are running into odd issues with Claims-Based Authentication and CRM 2016. Whenever we enable Claims-Based Authentication, the Internal Claims-Based Address returns 404 errors on ASPX resources, whereas static resources return properly. The External Address return both without an issue. As an example, here's our URLs we have configured:

```
Internal Base URL: https://internalcrm.organization.com:444/
External Base URL: https://org.organization.com:444/
```

When the HTTPS binding is set in IIS and Claims-Based is NOT enabled, all of the following URLs load successfully:

```
https://internalcrm.organization.com:444/test.aspx - works
https://internalcrm.organization.com:444/test.css - works
https://internalcrm.organization.com:444/test.html - works
https://org.organization.com:444/test.aspx - works
https://org.organization.com:444/test.css - works
https://org.organization.com:444/test.html - works
```

However, as soon as Claims-Based Authentication is enabled, we get the following behavior:

```
https://internalcrm.organization.com:444/test.aspx - 404 error
https://internalcrm.organization.com:444/test.css - works
https://internalcrm.organization.com:444/test.html - works
https://org.organization.com:444/test.aspx - works
https://org.organization.com:444/test.css - works
https://org.organization.com:444/test.html - works
```

Even weirder, with Claims-Based enabled, the following behavior is also observed:

```
https://internalcrm.organization.com:444/org/test.aspx - works
https://internalcrm.organization.com:444/org/test.css - 404 error
```

It almost appears as if when we enable Claims-Based Authentication, the CRM software somehow "redirects" the ASPX traffic on the Internal URL. I've tried enabling Failed Request Tracing in IIS but didn't see anything to go off of in there. Double-checked that there are no URL re-writes or redirects occurring. Don't see anything off in the IIS logs or ADFS logs indicating an error or something related to the 404s when they occur. As soon as we disable Claims-Based Authentication, the expected behavior returns.

Any ideas or tips on how to begin troubleshooting or things to check out/try would be extremely helpful.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Check https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn609803.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 to make sure you have everything correct